# How to concisely spread array of objects by ID?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iteration

I have an array of items:

```
const arr = [
  { id: 'abc', value: 2 },
  { id: 'def', value: 3 },
];
```

And I would like to create an object of items by `id`:

```
const obj = {
  abc: { id: 'abc', value: 2 },
  def: { id: 'def', value: 3 },
};
```

---

As far as I know, the most performant and concise way to do this is via  `Array.prototype.reduce`

```
const obj = arr.reduce((obj, entry) => {
  obj[entry.id] = entry;
  return obj;
}, {});
```

---

Are there **more performant** and **more concise** ways to perform the operation? What are they?

I know this is relatively subjective, and I'm open to suggestions how I can better phrase the question. Thanks.

Comment: "performant" and "concise" are sometimes traded one for the other. The `.reduce()` approach involves a function call per array element, while a simple `for` loop would not.

Comment: @Pointy I believe V8 engine may optimize and transpile the function into a lower-level relationship in C++, but that's a random guess

Comment: Indeed; worrying about stuff like this usually isn't worth it except at very large scale, and then *algorithmic* optimization is usually more valuable that *implementation* optimization.

Comment: It's like what "Mr. Erlang" Joe Armstrong says a lot: "just write the most beautiful code you can."

Answer (score 3):

You could make it a one-liner, utilizing the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 'abc', value: 2 },
  { id: 'def', value: 3 },
];

const obj = arr.reduce((obj, entry) => (obj[entry.id] = entry, obj), {});

console.log(obj);
```

It's less readable but somewhat more concise. It's up to you if it's worth it. Since you mentioned you were interested in [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), here's that solution, but see below for performance:

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 'abc', value: 2 },
  { id: 'def', value: 3 },
];

const obj = arr.reduce((obj, entry) => ({ ...obj, [entry.id]: entry }), {});

console.log(obj);
```

Yet another solution using argument spreading with `Object.assign`, but this code feels kind of clumsy to me and see below for performance:

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 'abc', value: 2 },
  { id: 'def', value: 3 },
];

const obj = Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(a => ({ [a.id]: a })));

console.log(obj);
```

---

As for the most performant solution, it's hard to beat `for`-loops:

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 'abc', value: 2 },
  { id: 'def', value: 3 },
];

const obj = {}, len = arr.length;
for(let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  let a = arr[i];
  obj[a.id] = a;
}

console.log(obj);
```

A quick benchmark on my machine gave the following results (on Firefox 66):

```
test case     | ops/s             | result
reduce-comma  | 22,248,622 ±2.83% |  6.89% slower
reduce-spread |  4,149,590 ±2.84% | 82.63% slower
object-assign |  1,809,170 ±0.69% | 92.43% slower
for-loop      | 23,895,193 ±2.51% | fastest
```

The second solution is much slower due to the use of the object spread operator, which clones the object on every iteration. I'm honestly not sure why `Object.assign` is even slower since most implementations of object spread are just `Object.assign` under the covers.

The difference between the last two options is *miniscule*, but it might be more significant on older browsers that aren't so well optimized. I'd recommend you run your own benchmarks if this truly is a performance critical application.

Comment: Implicit return is nice

Comment: I'm looking for something other than implicit return, maybe spread operator, function generator, iterator, es7, etc. but thank you for this answer

Comment: @neaumusic I've added a solution using object spread. IMO, it's not a good solution in terms of readability and definitely not in terms of performance. My personal preference would be the reduce w/ comma or your original code.